toDataUrl() freezes when trying to save blob on iPhone
I am trying to save a div locally with the HTML2Canvas dependency. Everything seems to be working perfect on desktop and Android phones, but on an iPhone there is am facing the following problem:
When trying to save the generated canvas with the following code, the browser freezes:
html2canvas(document.getElementById("theID"), { 
        scale: 5,
        allowTaint: true,
        imageTimeout: 15000,
        logging: true,
        useCORS: true,
    }).then(function (canvas) {
    if (saveLocally) {
        console.log("Start saving locally: ");
        console.log(canvas);
        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
            console.log(blob);
            var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        });
        console.log("finished creating screenshot");
        window.location.href = "https://example.com/cart";
    } 
});

The following output is written in the console:
DEBUG#1 0ms Starting document clone with size 414x720 scrolled to 0,-170
WARNING#1 1054ms Unable to restore scroll position for cloned document
DEBUG#1 1057ms Document cloned, element located at 76.15625,81.34375 with size 1066.4046630859375x1508.0211181640625 using computed rendering
DEBUG#1 1057ms Starting DOM parsing
DEBUG#1 1088ms Added image data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' fill-rule='evenodd' viewBox='0 0 88 23'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpath id='logo' d='M11.5 2.25c5.105 0 9.25 4.145 9.25 9.25s-4.145 9.25-9.25 9.25-9.2
DEBUG#1 1088ms Starting renderer for element at 76.15625,81.34375 with size 1067x1509
DEBUG#1 1089ms Canvas renderer initialized (1067x1509) with scale 5
DEBUG#1 1130ms Finished rendering
LOGStart saving locally: 
LOG[object HTMLCanvasElement]

I have found some information on the internet that the maximum size of a canvas on Ios is quite small, so maybe that could be the issue. But what is the solution on this? Is it possible to manually increase the maximum size for example?
I want my images to have the best quality (most of them are around 12MB).
Also trying to save the blob with saveAs(blob, 'customImage.png'); from the FileSaver library does freeze the window.
